# Cannot convert string to const char/string* to int*

Tags: c++, string, char, int

Firstly, I want to say that I'm a beginner. Sorry for my stupid questions.

My program should ask for the amount of words you want to put in. It's specifically said that this tab length is the length of pointers tab pointing to the words tab (may sound confusing, but English isn't my first language, my apologies, I also dont really understand pointers yet).

The words tab should also have exact length for each word, hence the `strlen`. What am I doing wrong?

```
int il,len;
string x;
cout<<"Amount of words: ";
cin>>il;
int **t;
t=new int*[il];
for(int i=0; i<il; i++)
{
    cout<<"Word: ";
    cin>>x;
    len=strlen(x);
    t[i]=new string[len];
    cout<<endl;
}
cout<<"You wrote:"<<endl;
for(int i=0; i<il; i++)
{
    cout<<t[i];
    delete [] t[i];
}
delete[] t;
```

Comment: `strlen` doesn't take a class string object but a const pointer to character string `char*`

Comment: What is tab? Do you mean the array (as in table)?

Comment: `t` is of type `int**`, and `t[i]` is of type `int*`. You cannot assign a `std::string*` object to `int*`. Coupled with some other errors in your code; You may want to glance over some [resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to help you understand C++ type system broader than we can explain here

Comment: Have you compiled this with some (all?) warnings enabled

Answer (score 1):

`strlen()` doesn't take a class `string` object but instead it takes a pointer to character string `char*`:

```
len = strlen(x); // error so correct it to:
len = x.length();
```

also you cannot initialize a pointer to an integers to class string:

```
int **t;
t[i]=new string[len];
```

- you really want an array of strings but the code is really a mess so if you want this how:

  ```
  int il;

  cout << "Amount of words: ";
  cin >> il;

  string *t;
  t = new string[il];

  for(int i = 0; i < il; i++)
  {
      cout << "Word: ";
      cin >> t[i]; // there's no need for a temporary string `x`; you can directly input the elements inside the loop
      cout << endl;
  }

  cout << "You wrote: " << endl;

  for( int i = 0; i < il; i++)
      cout << t[i] << endl;

  delete[] t;
  ```

Comment: Lets be frank. The code is a mess. It should be dumped and started again

Comment: @EdHeal: yes you are true! thus I suggest this code for him/her

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>` could be an improvement.

Comment: @YSC: yes it is a good idea but the OP maybe doesn't seem to have some background about it